# How to make container-fluid inside my navbar having its same height (and so on for all the links inside)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to style the links of my Bootstrap navbar in such a way that a shadow appear under them when you are over them w/ the mouse. The html code is:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid attempt">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand text-uppercase"
          >Valerio Valente</a
        >
```

Unfortunately, this makes the **container-fluid** inside the **navbar** shorter than the latter and, therefore, the shadow appearing under the links is above the end of the navbar (so ugly!). I've tried to solve this by manually setting the container's height w/ css but it seems that *auto, 100%* and *inherit* don't work at all! I've also tried to use the Bootstrap class **h-100** it didn't work.
I could remove the Bootstrap's *.navbar* and do it by myself but the Bootstrap's one is already styled to be responsive for mobile for which I have an hamburger toggle that i would like not to lose.

Comment: Your question didn't say how much you need to expand nor where you're applying the shadow. It would be good if you could update your question with a functional snippet. You can increase the height of the navbar by adding margin-bottom to the `navbar-nav` ul list.

Comment: You're absolutely right, however, meanwhile I solved the problem by adding to the .container-fluid padding-top and padding-bottom. This resulted in an increased size of the navbar that I managed by adding (again in the .container-fluid) a negative margin-top and margin-bottom of the same amount of the padding. Hope this can help others having same troubles of mine.